# How to properly set up a Windows Desktop application to send emails via Office 365?

Tags: email, azure-active-directory, office365, desktop-application, mailkit

We have a desktop application that sends emails on behalf of the user (for Invoices, Receipts and the like).  Previously we had been using basic SMTP authentication for this but now we are adding support for OAuth 2.0 for services that will require it like Exchange 365 online.  So the application needs to authenticate against any arbitrary Exchange 365 server the user is running and send emails with attachments to any number of recipients (their Customers).  This is all new to us so I wnat to make sure we are settings things up correctly.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Application is registered on our corporate Azure AD site.  I've assigned it Mail.Send permission (among others).
   [image: Azure AD permissions]
2. We're using the Microsoft Identity Client library for the authentication.  All of the function calls appear to work, I get the login prompt, sign in, and verify the sign in on my phone's Authenticator app.  The functions return an token.  Given that we want to authenticate against any organization/domain on Office 365 I think we need to use the "common" TenantID is this correct?

   ```
   Dim Options As New PublicClientApplicationOptions
   Options.ClientId = pClientID
   Options.TenantId = pTenantID
   Options.RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"

   Dim publicClientApplication As IPublicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(Options).Build

   Dim scopes() As String = {
       "email",
       "offline_access",
       "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Send"
   }

   Try

       Dim CM_EmailServerSetting As ICM_EmailServerSetting = CCM_EmailServerSettingServices.GetEmailServerSettingForApplication()

       Dim authToken As AuthenticationResult = Await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(Me).WithLoginHint(CM_EmailServerSetting.EmailAddress).ExecuteAsync()
   ```
3. Then we connect to the specified server with SMTP protocol but using the OAuth2 objects.

   Dim oauth2 As MailKit.Security.SaslMechanism
   Dim EmailClient As New Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()
   EmailClient.Connect(CM_EmailServerSetting.SMTPServerAddress, CM_EmailServerSetting.Port)

   ```
       If (EmailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER")) Then
           oauth2 = New MailKit.Security.SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken)
       Else
           oauth2 = New MailKit.Security.SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken)
       End If

       Await EmailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2)
   ```

The above call to AuthenticateAsync throws an exception that SMTP AUTH is disabled for the tenant.  We seem to be attempting to connecting using OAuth2 protocol so what am I missing?  Is there some other permission I need to grant on Azure?  (This is all new to us)

Answer (score 0):

Code was fine.  SMTP was disabled for the test accounts.

Sorry everyone.  Q & A preserved just in case someone else falls into the same trap.